# Shortest way to get a TypeError

Tags: code-golf, python, error-message

It's simple, simply write the shortest code to raise a `TypeError`.

In Python you can do:

```
raise TypeError
```

However it should be shorter with a code that gives a `TypeError` without raising it.

Comment: this isn't really defined for other languages. You've also immediately answered the shortest possible way for Python...

Comment: @JoKing I answer one out of 3 or more, feel free to post the other 3 byte ones

Comment: This shouldn't be closed, but it's only well-defined for one language (Python)

Comment: I now made this a python golf

Comment: I'm retracting my close vote, since this is pretty clear. But I'm downvoting this because it is an extremely simple challenge with an obvious optimal answer with no possibility of improvement.

Comment: Oh right, you might want to post your challenges to the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/) before you post this here.

Comment: maybe add the `tips` tag since it's language-specific.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```python
for chr1 in range(32, 128):
  for chr2 in range(32, 128):
    for chr3 in range(32, 128):
      code = chr(chr1) + chr(chr2) + chr(chr3)
      try:
        output = exec(code, {})
      except TypeError:
        print(code)
      except:
        pass
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BCsIwEEX3nuIvE@ymyUYEl97AC5Q42m6SMJ1Cg3j2aKTRCrr78N6biUn64G3Ol8BwPbcYPLjzV1LWNGjNTu83wELNb/rm9h8HXDgTDkVS5Y3Gtm6z2lYvunCqJRAmiZM8a5rJqXKpwe1eVZodRcEpRToyB/50kQcvL//bXRndOOb8AA)

A naive search may result that you cannot trigger a TypeError within 2 characters. You may get a TypeError with 3 characters. All solutions including:

### 1. Math operator, non-numeric types

- Math operator including `+`, `-`, `~`
- Non-numeric types including `""`, `()`, `[]`, `id`, `{}`

```
+[]
-""
~id
```

### 2. Invoke number as function

```python
0()
```

### 3. Matrix multiplication between numbers

`@` is `__matmul__` in python, [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python)

```python
0@0
```

### 4. Binary operator with float / complex number

```python
~0.
~.0
~0j
```

### 5. Iterate over number

Thanks to [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) to point out this.

You may iterate some variable by star operator. And `()` for a tuple may be omitted.

```python
*0,
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 4 bytes

```javascript
1.()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/31BPQ/P///8A)

## [Output]

`.code.tio:1: TypeError: 1 is not a function
1.()
  ^
TypeError: 1 is not a function
    at .code.tio:1:3`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.7/), 3 bytes

```
+''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X1td/f9/AA)

Comment: Uh oh. I can not make my program less than 3 bytes. Anyway, nice trick!

Comment: @A__ Yeah, anyway you can post the other 3 byte ones

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 3 bytes

This is self-explanatory. The unary - operator does not take a string argument. This was covered in @tsh's solution above.

```
-""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X1dd/f9/AA)

Another one:

```
~id
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/vy4z5f9/AA)

Comment: Haha yeah nice idea i still have more than 2 different styles in mind tho

Comment: yeah, double quotes and that's about it

Comment: There is also [`-id` and `+id`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Xzcz5f9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 1 [byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Throws `TypeError: U.í is not a function`

```
í
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7Q) (Errors are displayed below the output field)

---

Or, a bit less trivial:

### [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Throws `TypeError: (U++) is not a function`

```
°(
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=sCg)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 3 bytes

```
+[]
```

It gives an `TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'list`

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.7/), 3 bytes

```
0()
```

raises a `TypeError`

Comment: I just made a program that finds all the possible combinations for one and two bytes, `exec`s that, and no two bytes raised a `TypeError`. Therefore, raising an `TypeError` with less than three bytes is impossible.